# how to parse data present in the "id="title"" into placeholder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="loadFile(this)" multiple> 
<p><b>Title:</b> <span id="title"></span></p>
</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="#title">
```

I want send data of `id=title` into `placeholder`, what can i replace in double quotes("") in order to get that title value?

Comment: Not clear. What data exactly, what double quotes?

Comment: in paceholder double codes i want to display the data which i get from span id

Comment: this is my script below
    /**
     * Loading the tags using the FileAPI.
     */
    function loadFile(input) {
      var file = input.files[0],
        url = file.urn || file.name;

      ID3.loadTags(url, function() {
        showTags(url);
      }, {
        tags: ["title","artist","album","genre","picture"],
        dataReader: ID3.FileAPIReader(file)
      });
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to place the text from `<span id="title"></span>` and place it into the `placeholder` attribute of your `input` element, you will want to improve your HTML First.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <input type="file" id="file-input" onchange="loadFile(this)" multiple /> 
  <p><b>Title:</b> <span id="title"></span></p>
</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="" id="title-input" />
```

Then you can use jQuery to accomplish the task.

**JavaScript**

```
$("#title-input").attr("placeholder", $("#title").text());
```

The issue is that there is nothing to trigger this. I suspect that `loadFile()` populates `#title`. So You may want to look at that and see if you can add to it.

Or, something like:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <input type="file" id="file-input" onchange="loadFile(this)" multiple /> 
  <p><b>Title:</b> <span id="title"></span></p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
  $("#title").click(function(){
    var currentValue = $(this).text();
    $(this).hide();
    var $textBox = $("<input>", {
      id: "edit-title",
      value: currentValue
    });
    var $saveLink = $("<a>", {
      href: "#"
    }).html("Save").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#title").html($("#edit-title").val());
      $("#edit-title").remove();
      $(this).remove();
      $("#title").show();
    });
    $saveLink.insertAfter($("#title"));
    $textBox.insertAfter($("#title"));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is (add an id="textinput" to input type):

```
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="loadFile(this)" multiple> 
<p><b>Title:</b> <span id="title"></span></p>
</div>
<input type="text" id="textinput" placeholder="#title">

<script>
document.getElementById("textinput").placeholder = document.getElementById("title").textContent;
</script>
```

Comment: im not getting value of id in placeholder , instead i'm getting #title

Comment: Hello Susmitha, here the working fiddle.js, so your code must work also:
https://jsfiddle.net/ceatos/tudcqxgq/

Comment: i'm uploading a audio file , i want title to be placed in placeholder as soon as i upload

Comment: the above js fiddle didn't work, it displays same #title in the place holder

Comment: sorry but "some title" remains in place holder value it does not change

Comment: So you want to upload an audio file and it's title must be in the placeholder and the title also(?). My jsfiddle code getting the info from the title section to the placeholder. Maybe it need more code details for the exact solution (how to select the audio file, how to put the title text into the span?)

ps: The code above you selected as solution is the same as mine.

Comment: i need only title of the uploaded file in the place of placeholder

Answer (score 0):

First modify your html a bit like this:

```
<p><b>Title:</b> <span id="title">SomeText</span></p>

<input type="text" placeholder="#title" id="txtBox">
```

Then put this javascript code if you don't want to use jQuery.

```
<script>
    var value = document.getElementById('title').textContent;
    document.getElementById('txtBox').setAttribute("placeholder", value);
</script>
```